# Retrival of character string from email addresses

Tags: c, regex, bison, lex, nlp

I am trying to come up with a way in flex through which I can extract only the character series from a list of email addresses.
The email addresses are valid. Example

```
Input: a12l3i.ce@example.com
output: alice
```

So far, I came with the regular expression `([^@]+)` through which I can extract the username part of the email. However, without the use of input/unput (which is not allowed in flex) can we retrive the text from the email username ? If yes, can you suggest me a regular expression or any other method for that ? (Perhaps a grammar in Bison)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify the transformation from `a12l3i.ce` to `alice` as it isn't very self-explanatory.  If you consider `[a-zA-Z]` as "names":

```
%option noyywrap
%%
[a-zA-Z]+|\n   ECHO;
@.*\n          putchar ('\n');
.              /* ignore */
```

will output those.

Answer (score 2):

You're really trying to use a wierd tool for doing this. It's possible to do it, but it's really not a very good solution to build a grammar for it. I would suggest that you use your existing expression of getting the user name and just replace the non a-z characters using code in the action of the lexer file.

This code strips away everything from `yytext` that isn't a letter. `yytext` is a modifiable buffer, so this sort of thing is allowed as long as you don't lengthen the buffer.

```
char* r = yylex;
for (char *p = yylex; *p; ++p) {
    if ((*p >= 'a' && *p < 'z') || (*p >= 'A' && *p < 'Z')) {
    *r++ = *p;
    }
}
*r = 0;
```

That will result in `alice` from your given example string, provided you have everything up to the `@` sign using the lexer rule that you've already given.